# Generate Preprocessed File in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any possibility to see preprocessed files before they are compiled in Xcode? In Visual Studio has the option "Generate Preprocessed File" (options->C/C++->preprocessor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on a file and choose "Preprocess"...

Comment: I never seen this option:) Thanks! It works:) Very useful to find macro errors!

Comment: Right clicking on a file in Xcode 4.0 doesn't give this option and an Apple employee is asking me for "a preprocessed file" saying that "The attached test case is including header files which are not provided." regarding a Radar report of mine. Anyone know how it works in 4.0?

Comment: @Kalle see my answer below. I hope this is in time to help you.

Comment: @objektivs Yeah, it was gone in the (beta) I was using, but they re-added it. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 20):

In Xcode 5:

1. Select an implementation file.
2. From the menu: Product | Perform Action | Preprocess "YourClassName.m"

Comment: Thanks for updating this thread. I searched a little for the options, but I didn't think to update this old thread. +1

Comment: Also you can keep a live Preprocess view on the right side with the Assistant editor.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4:

1. Select an implementation file
2. From the menu: Product | Generate Output | Generate Preprocessed File

Hope this helps.