# What is the cause of the "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" error in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker

I'd like to know the reason these files (or possibly others in my project) don't want to link.  As far as I know it's okay to leave out the constructor and destructor if you define them in the .h file, correct?  I did this with another .h in my project and it isn't complaining.  What's going on?

The error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BasicArena::BasicArena()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

AreaInterface.h (for the purposes of the assignment, we are not allowed to edit this file)

```
class ArenaInterface
{
    public:
        ArenaInterface(){}
        virtual ~ArenaInterface(){}
        // lots of pure virtuals here
}
```

BasicArena.h

```
#ifndef __rpg__BasicArena__
#define __rpg__BasicArena__

#include <stdio.h>
#include "ArenaInterface.h"
#include "Cleric.h"

using namespace std;

class BasicArena : public ArenaInterface
{
public:
    BasicArena() {}
    ~BasicArena() {}
    virtual bool addFighter(string info);
    virtual bool removeFighter(string name);
    virtual FighterInterface* getFighter(string name);
    virtual int getSize();

private:
    vector<FighterInterface*> fighters;
};

#endif /* defined(__rpg__BasicArena__) */
```

BasicArena.cpp

```
#include "BasicArena.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
// member function definitions here
```

Cleric.h:

```
#ifndef __rpg__Cleric__
#define __rpg__Cleric__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "FighterInterface.h"

using namespace std;

class Cleric : public FighterInterface
{
public:
    Cleric(string nam, int HP, int str, int spd, int mag, int dmg) : name(nam), maxHP(HP), strength(str), speed(spd), magic(mag), damage(dmg){}
    ~Cleric() {}
    // lots of functions and data
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BasicArena.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    BasicArena testarena;
    cout << "It works.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Commenting out the declarations/definitions of BasicArena allow the program to run, but leaves me with the question of whether this is acceptable/desired for the final program.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error please?

Comment: Sure thing.  I updated it with the error message.

Comment: And you have a `#include "Cleric.h"` that you haven't shown.

Comment: I'm just using Xcode...but perhaps there's some setting I need to change?  The "Cleric.h" references another .h and .cpp which seem to be working okay.

Comment: @Brandon: The code you've shown here is fine. It's likely that there is some other piece of your code that you haven't shown that contains the error.

Comment: I added some of the Cleric.h file if that helps uncover the error.  Is it possible for the error to be located somewhere else in the files I have shown?  I just don't want to make the question too long.

Comment: Could you upload the output of the preprocessor for `main.cpp`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266650/generate-preprocessed-file-in-xcode It'll be a massive file, so it might be easier to upload it to gist.github.com or similar.

Comment: If you move the definition of the BasicArena() default constructor out of the .h file and into a .cpp file, does the linker error go away?  (just curious; AFAICT it should work the way you have it as well)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Or comment it out all together...

Comment: @ BillLynch I'll try to figure out how to upload the preprocessor output - the method on that link you posted doesn't seem to work for my version of Xcode

@JeremyFriesner I tried moving the definition to the .cpp file already and it didn't work : /  However, commenting it out as Bill suggested made it at least compile and run.  Will my class still work without a new constructor?  Can I just use the constructor from the parent class?

Comment: @Brandon: If you're on the most recent os x / xcode, it should be Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess main.cpp

Comment: @BillLynch I updated the post with the preprocessed main.cpp.

Comment: @Brandon: The error you are seeing is making very little sense to me. My only remaining guess is that there are earlier lines in your error message that would tell us that `BasicArena` is still abstract. But if I remember correctly that error message would look different.

Comment: Here's what I'm wondering - if I define a child class from a parent, do I have to redeclare and redefine the constructor and destructor?  If so, do they need to be virtual functions in the parent class to do so?  Only the destructor is a virtual in this parent class.  Of course, I have a similar situation with the Cleric class which inherits from a parent similar to ArenaInterface.  I'm so confused.

Comment: @Brandon: Oh Wait. I see that you're saying that commenting it out worked. So, that makes very little sense to me that doing that fixed the problem. But in a sane world, if you define no constructor you'll be given an implicit one that takes no arguments and has an empty body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I don't know exactly how this worked, but somehow after commenting out the BasicArena constructor and destructor, running the program (it compiled and ran at that point) *then reinstating them* it compiles and runs as far as I know with the same code it originally had.  I am at a loss.  I'm just glad it works.

Most likely this code had a small error (such as a missing semicolon) that was causing the linker issue.